# How can I access serial port of my GCP instance, It asks password and I never used it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My GCP instance is not booting peoperly, I am trying to connect using serial port 1 and key  but it asks password which I never set.
I enabled it
gcloud compute instances add-metadata teyeprodv1 --metadata serial-port-enable=1
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port user@instance-name  --ssh-key-file  ~/.ssh/key.pem --zone us-central1-a

Second command ask username and password. I know username but not password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQwl6.png)

Answer (score 9):

After [enabling serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connecting_to_a_serial_console_with_a_login_prompt), you should create a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to create a user which will allow you to connect to the VM.

1. On your VM instance, click the Edit button at the top of the page.
2. Under Custom metadata, click Add item.
3. Set 'Key' to 'startup-script' and set 'Value' to this script:

   #! /bin/bash
   adduser USERNAME 
   echo 'USERNAME:PASSWORD' | chpasswd 
   usermod -aG google-sudoers USERNAME
4. Click Save and then click RESET on the top of the page. You might need to wait for some time for the instance to reboot.
5. Click on 'Connect to serial port' in the page.
6. In the new window, you might need to wait a bit and press Enter; then, you should see the login prompt.
7. Login using the USERNAME and PASSWORD you provided.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for reply. Please keep in touch with me for fixing the issue. I tried but no to avail. How can I verify if user is created or not. I mean script run successfully or not.It is prompting  Login incorrect.

Comment: The startup script may vary depending on the OS. Which OS are you using??

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Just tested in 16.04, the script is good.
Make sure to set key 'startup-script' and value the script from #3.
After that you should save and reset the VM.

Comment: I also tested the script in Ubuntu 16.04, It ask password.                                                                                    Adding user `itsec' ...
Adding new group `itsec' (1004) ...
Adding new user `itsec' (1003) with group `itsec' ...
Creating home directory `/home/itsec' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:

Comment: It could be that your OS has an issue.  
I would recommend you to create a new instance and attach the disk of this one to the new instance 
 [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk).
After mounting the disk you can investigate ssh or simply copy data from old disk to the new one.

Comment: I planned and tried. but there was some issue. can I mount /dev/sdb  with /opt            I should run this command.                                                                               sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/[DEVICE_ID]

Comment: The step you have described is in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting) for formatting the new disk that you want to use. It is deleting all data from the specified disk, if you are attaching an existing disk with data, you should skip this step.
Make sure to replace all the text in brackets [ ] with your information.

Comment: @Ivan I am not able to login using start up script its ubuntu 18.04 . ANy help appreciated

Comment: It doesn't look like this solution has worked for anyone, probably time to remove it as an answer...

Comment: The last line of your script, should it be `usermod -aG google-sudoers username`.  If not, what is the `test` user's relevance?  I made that change and it worked for me.